# How can I align span text with text in other columns?

Tags: html, css

I have a row with six columns of image and text here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xTuk.png

I want to align the two-line text (e.g. Resources and Reserves) with "Exploration" and "Geological Data". https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeAzg.png

Adding a margin below the image doesn't do the trick, nor does adding a margin above the text... also tried setting a `min-height` for the icon, but that doesn't do it either.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please share your code, and consider to use flexbox

Answer (score 0):

Using flexbox you can easily align your text on "top". 
This is default flexbox behaviour and does align your text on "baseline":

```css
.container{
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowarp;
}

.text{
  max-width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<div class="container">

  <div class="imgt">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/20x20">
    <div>Some Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgt">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/20x20">
    <div class="text">Some Long long Text</div>
  </div>
</div>


</html>
```

I assume you have a `margin-top: auto;` and `margin-bottom: auto;`, or some flexbox properties like `align-items: center;` somewhere, that your text gets centered inside the div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex styles to obtain your desired results. I created an example showing how the align-items: stretch; property will help with keeping icons/images/and content aligned with siblings.

Live example: https://codepen.io/SROwl/pen/xNrRmw

HTML:

```
<h3> align content top </h3>
<div class="bucket-row">
  <div class="bucket">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/85x85">
    <span>Single Line</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bucket">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/85x85">
    <span>Double Line Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bucket">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/85x85">
    <span>Double Line Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bucket">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/85x85">
    <span>Single Line</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bucket">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/85x85">
    <span>Triplen Extra Line Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bucket">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/85x85">
    <span>Double Line Title</span>
  </div>
</div>
<h3> align content bottom </h3>
<div class="bucket-row content-end">
  <div class="bucket">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/85x85">
    <span>Single Line</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bucket">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/85x85">
    <span>Double Line Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bucket">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/85x85">
    <span>Double Line Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bucket">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/85x85">
    <span>Single Line</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bucket">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/85x85">
    <span>Triplen Extra Line Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bucket">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/85x85">
    <span>Double Line Title</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.bucket-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  .bucket {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 85px;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    img {
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
  } 

  &.content-end {
    .bucket {
      span {
        margin-top: auto;
      }
    }
  }
}
```